# Problem displaying my information on my application

Tags: android, kotlin

here I am creating a small online notepad application.
I have a display problem with my recyclerView.When my page loads, the cities are not displayed directly when I open my fragment, but the information is displayed only when I click on my dialog box to add a city.
I tried entering a city name directly in my "cities" variable and it works. I think this comes from my return from "onConvertDataFirestoreToCity ()" function but after 3 days of head box, I still don't understand. Thank you for the help

```
class CityFragmentPresentation : Fragment(), CityAdapter.CityItemListener {

val db = Firebase.firestore
val TAG = "com.croustibat.ampc93.CityFragmentPresentation"

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): CityFragmentPresentation = CityFragmentPresentation()
}

interface CityFragmentListener {
    fun onCitySelected(city: City)
    fun onEmptyCity()
}

var listener: CityFragmentListener? = null

private lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
private lateinit var titleCityName: String
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: CityAdapter
private var cities = onConvertDataFirestoreToCity()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    titleCityName = activity?.intent?.getStringExtra("TitleCityName").toString()

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city_presentation, container, false)
    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_fragment)
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_city)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.cities_recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    return view
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    adapter = CityAdapter(cities, this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        onOptionsItemSelected(it)
    }
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { activity?.finish() }
    toolbar.title = titleCityName
}


override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.add_city -> {
            showCreateCityDialog()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

fun showCreateCityDialog() {
    val createCityFragment = CreateCityDialogFragment()
    createCityFragment.listener = object : CreateCityDialogFragment.CreateCityDialogListener {
        override fun OnDialogPositiveClick(cityName: String) {
            addCity(City(cityName))
        }

        override fun OnDialogNegativeClick() {}

    }
    fragmentManager?.let {
        createCityFragment.show(it, "CreateDialogCityFragment")
    }
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
private fun addCity(city: City) {
    db.collection("cities")
        .add(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            cities.add(city)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Log.d(TAG, "Ville enregistrée")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { w -> Log.d(TAG, "Erreur de sauvegarde de la ville", w) }
}

override fun onCitySelected(city: City) {
    listener?.onCitySelected(city)
}

override fun onCityDeleted(city: City) {
    cities.remove(city)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
fun onConvertDataFirestoreToCity(): MutableList<City> {
    val cities = mutableListOf<City>()
    db.collection("cities")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            it.forEach {
                val city = it.toObject<City>()
                cities.add(city)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Conversion réussie !!!")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { w -> Log.d(TAG, "Conversion impossible !!!", w) }
    return cities
}
```

}

Comment: Please try adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `recyclerView.adapter = adapter` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private var cities = mutableListOf<City>()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = CityAdapter(cities, this)
        onConvertDataFirestoreToCity()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            onOptionsItemSelected(it)
        }
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { activity?.finish() }
        toolbar.title = titleCityName
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    fun onConvertDataFirestoreToCity() {
        db.collection("cities")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                it.forEach {
                    val city = it.toObject<City>()
                    cities.add(city)
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Log.d(TAG, "Conversion réussie !!!")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { w -> Log.d(TAG, "Conversion impossible !!!", w) }
    }
```